# iPhone - Load a UIView from a nib file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, subclassing

I am subclassing UIView trying to load the view i have dropped in interface builder from a nib file.
I get the following error on the return line:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:'**

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                        loadNibNamed:@"MyView" 
                        owner:nil 
                        options:nil];
    if (self = [objects objectAtIndex:0])
    {
    }
    return [self retain];
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are doing something very strange)

`loadNibNamed:owner:options:` will call `initWithCoder:` to instantiate your view from xib. But you are calling `loadNibNamed:owner:options:` from `initWithCoder:`. Infinite recursion?

To load view from xib you can do the next:

```
@implementation MyView

+ (MyView*) myView
{
  NSArray* array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:nil options:nil];
  return [array objectAtIndex:0]; // assume that MyView is the only object in the xib
}

@end
```

Comment: Is there anything special you have to do in order to use `MyView` in another nib, besides set the Custom Class to `MyView`?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing `self = [objects objectAtIndex:0]` you should loop through the array and make sure you are getting the right object, for example:

```
for (id object in objects) {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[YourClassName class]])
        self = (YourClassName*)object;
}
```

That said, I've always done this a layer up and pulled the reference right out of the `UIViewController`. This breaks the abstraction layer though, since the class that just wants to use the view would need to know what Nib its in:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];
YourClassName* view = (YourClassName*)vc.view;
[vc release];
```

Comment: that is not the problem, there is only 1 object in the array, and the first one is always the correct one

Comment: and i don't want to use a viewController, All i want is a custom view generated from a nib